# Invalid scope message is displayed when trying to get data from graph api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**What I have done**

- I have a Facebook App that I have logged in
- I have integrated Facebook SDK in my sample app
- I have followed all the instructions here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android
- I have even added the sha key to developer account

**What I am trying to do**

- I am trying to get my logged in Facebook URL from my sample app

**What I have tried**

```
class FacebookSocialHandleService(
    private val context: Activity,
    private var callbackManager: CallbackManager?,
) : SocialHandleInterface {


    override fun getProfileLink() {
        println("Getting the profile link from facebook")
        facebookLogin();
        performFacebookLogin()
    }


    private fun performFacebookLogin() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance()?.logInWithReadPermissions(context, listOf("user_link"))
    }


    private fun facebookLogin() {
        // loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance()
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(
            callbackManager,
            object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                    val request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.accessToken
                    ) { obj, response ->
                        try {
                            if (obj != null) {
                                MLogger.d(tag, obj.toString())
                                if (obj.has("link")) {
                                    MLogger.d(tag, "Link is as follows!")
                                    MLogger.d(tag, obj.optString("link"))
                                } else {
                                    MLogger.d(tag, "Link is not found")
                                }
                            } else {
                                MLogger.d(tag, "Graph request json was null")
                                MLogger.d(tag, response!!.error!!.errorMessage!!)
                            }
                        } catch (e: JSONException) {
                            MLogger.d(tag, "Facebook Authentication Failed.")
                        }
                    }
                    val parameters = Bundle()
                    parameters.putString("fields","id,name,link")
                    request.parameters = parameters
                    request.executeAsync()
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    MLogger.v("LoginScreen", "---onCancel")
                }

                override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                    // here write code when get error
                    MLogger.v("LoginScreen", "----onError: "
                            + error.message)
                }
            })
    }
    
    
}
```

**Whats happening - Getting this message **

[image]

Comment: Are you testing this with a user that has a role in the app?

Comment: Yes, you need to test this with accounts that have a role in the app (admin/developer/tester), and you will need to submit the app for review afterwards, before you can ask any other users for the permission.

Comment: _"I am trying to get name like this Ex: `https://www.facebook.com/Micheal`"_ - you won't be able to get _that_ any more; Facebook removed API access to the user name a while ago. At most, using this permission, you will get a tokenized link that will work for friends of the user only, and redirect them to the real profile address.

Comment: @CBroe ... Okay, say we get the tokenized link of `my profile` using the graph API using the param `user_link`. Say someone who is not my friend on Facebook clicks that link can that person navigate to my profile. This is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: No, they can not, because as https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ explicitly explains: _"`link`, string - A link to the person's Timeline. The link **will only resolve if the person clicking the link is logged into Facebook and is a friend of the person whose profile is being viewed.**"_ - _"This is what I am trying to achieve"_ - Facebook has deliberately made that impossible.

Comment: @CBroe .... What .... Omg ... Is there a way to validate the tokenized link is valid or not ?... What is the best way to add validation for handling this?

Comment: Check if the user you want to show the link to, is friends with the profile owner first? Of course you will need `user_friends` permission from both of them then.